# Point at a given Run flow document wpf

Tags: wpf, navigation, flowdocument

I've got a FlowDocumentPageViewer with dynamic content. The flow document is made of paragraphs, each run in the paragraph contains a word. I'm trying to navigate to a given run, so I got the method which will return me the run I want.
But once I got this Run how can I navigate to it, with automatic page change?

For example I select the last run in a page, the next run is in the next page. How do I navigate to the next page from there?
I had a look at the TextPointer but I'm not sure this will help here.

Thanks for your help, 
Boris

Comment: I still haven't found the solution, if you guys had any idea it would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution, once you get a pointer to your FrameworkElement, you will have to call `FrmkElement.BringIntoView()`, it will automatically change page in the PageFlowDocumentViewer.